# App is Rejected: crashes on launch

Tags: ios, crash, app-store, crash-reports

I have an app for iPhone, which is already in the App Store but i made some new features and tried to submit to the App Store.

On 1st time submission

> We were unable to review your app, as it crashed on launch on the following device(s):
>
> iPhone 4S running iOS 8.1- iPhone 5C running iOS 8.1- iPhone 5S
>   running iOS 8.1- iPhone 6 running iOS 8.1- iPhone 6 Plus running iOS
>   8.1- iPod Touch Fifth Generation running iOS 8.1
>
> We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.

I already tested it with test flight in many devices, but i can't reproduce the error.

Theres any way i can simulate the environment that apple uses to test it, or maybe analyze the crash report any way?

Crash Report

https://www.dropbox.com/s/h60llp5zzkrodln/ezmall_2015-05-21-214647_p01a019-ph-4s-DN00AO6A-10.txt?dl=0

Comment: They will have provided a crash report. What does it say?

Comment: Just added the Crash report in the question

Answer (score 1):

In the crash log it shows you why it is crashing...

> reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary
>   initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from
>   objects[2]'

You're best just pasting the crash log into the question. Makes it easier to read.

Anyway, you can't put `nil` into a dictionary. The result is that the app will terminate.

Without seeing any code it's pretty much impossible to determine why this is happening but it should give you something to look for.

In fact, it looks like you're attempting to create a dictionary with 3 or more items and the 3rd one is nil.

Comment: The problem is, in DEV ou with test flight i can't reproduce the error (the app just works fine).

Theres any way i can reproduce the environment that apple uses? Maybe that way the crash occurs

Comment: @ViniciusAlbino you could try to symbolicate the crash log. Might tell you the class that's crashing. How complex is your app startup though? Is it so complex that you can't find the bit that is creating a dictionary? Might be worth just looking through the code. Maybe post some here.